# Asynchronous process execution in Activiti

Tags: java, spring-boot, workflow, activiti, bpmn

I am new to Activiti, and was going through [this link](http://www.nurkiewicz.com/2011/01/activiti-processes-and-executions.html) to understand programmatic usage of Activiti Engine.

I would want to trigger a process start asynchronously, and get notified when it completes execution (success or error). Is that somehow possible? I will be using all ServiceTasks.

Answer (score 2):

To start your process asynchronously, you need to set all the servicetasks to "asynchronous" in your asynchronous bpm diagram.

You can pass execution variables between your service tasks.

Starting an asynchronously process can be done with the 
startProcessInstanceByKey method